# How do i fix a throw error when integrating Python and C++ Code? Is the issue with the way that I am calling the function from Python to c++?

Tags: python, c++

Ok so I am trying to run a program that uses C++ and Python. The C++ code calls functions from the Python code. The code in C++ that is above main() was already provided and is not supposed to be edited. However, I keep getting the following error: Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
**pValue** was nullptr. When running the code with options 1 & 2. How do I fix this?

C++ Code

```
    #include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;



void CallProcedure(string pName)
{
    char* procname = new char[pName.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, pName.c_str());

    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* my_module = PyImport_ImportModule("PythonCode");
    PyErr_Print();
    PyObject* my_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(my_module, procname);
    PyObject* my_result = PyObject_CallObject(my_function, NULL);
    Py_Finalize();

    delete[] procname;
}

int callIntFunc(string proc, string param)
{
    char* procname = new char[proc.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, proc.c_str());

    char* paramval = new char[param.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(paramval, param.c_str());


    PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pValue = nullptr, * presult = nullptr;
    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();
    // Build the name object
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"PythonCode");
    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    // pDict is a borrowed reference 
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, procname);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        pValue = Py_BuildValue("(z)", paramval);
        PyErr_Print();
        presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    //printf("Result is %d\n", _PyLong_AsInt(presult));
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    // Clean up
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    // clean 
    delete[] procname;
    delete[] paramval;


    return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);
}


int callIntFunc(string proc, int param)
{
    char* procname = new char[proc.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, proc.c_str());

    PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pValue = nullptr, * presult = nullptr;
    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();
    // Build the name object
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"PythonCode");
    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    // pDict is a borrowed reference 
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, procname);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        pValue = Py_BuildValue("(i)", param);
        PyErr_Print();
        presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    //printf("Result is %d\n", _PyLong_AsInt(presult));
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    // Clean up
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    // clean 
    delete[] procname;

    return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);
}


    void main()
    {
    int clicked = 0;
    do {
        int n = 0;
        cout << "1: Display a Multiplication Table" << endl << "2: Double a Value" << endl << "3: 
        Exit" << endl;
        cin >> clicked;
        switch (clicked) {
        case 1:
        {   cout << "Please enter a numerical value . . ."<< endl;
            cin >> n;
            cout << callIntFunc("(MultiplicationTable)",n); }
            break;
        case 2:
            {cout << "Please enter a numerical value . . ."<< endl;
            cin >> n;
            int dValue = callIntFunc("(DoubleValue)",n);
            cout << "Doubled Value:  " << dValue << endl; }
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "You are now exiting the program!" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please enter a valid selection . . ."<< endl;
            break;
        }
        } while (clicked != 3);

        }



Python code

    import re
    import string


    def printsomething():
    print("Hello from python!")


    def PrintMe(v):
    print("You sent me: " + v)
    return 100


    def MultiplicationTable(v):
    v = int(v)
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(v, " x ", i, " = ", (v * i))


    def DoubleValue(v):
    return v * 2


    def SquareValue(v):
    return v * v
```

Comment: If this is running in a debugger (it had better be!) then you should be able to tell us on which line of code (which call into python) the exception gets thrown. There may be a "break on exception" option somewhere in your IDE. Better yet, reduce the code to a minimum reproducible example by deleting as much of it as possible until all it does is throw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the python function to return 0 as follows;

```
 def MultiplicationTable(v):
 v = int(v)
 for i in range(1, 11):
    print(v, " x ", i, " = ", (v * i))
  return 0
```